# Is it safe to evaporate hydrogen peroxide in test tube?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, safety

Is it safe to evaporate 3% hydrogen peroxide in test tube? What will be left in the test tube if the solution totally evaporated?

Comment: Don't do chemical experiments if you cannot predict what will happen! You are bound to injure yourself and others!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to immersed metal in hydrogen peroxide in a closed container? In hydrochloric acid solution?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80217/is-it-safe-to-immersed-metal-in-hydrogen-peroxide-in-a-closed-container-in-hydr)

Comment: @andselisk This definitely isn't a duplicate.

Comment: At what concentration and is it aqueous solution?

Comment: I just used the one that can be bought from pharmacies, with 3% concentration only.

Answer (score 2):

**NO**, *do not* do this.  It is too dangerous.

Pure $\ce{H2O2}$ is known to be an explosive material, especially if heated it may undergo thermal decomposition.  This is one reason why this chemical is sold as an aqueous solution, most often at a maximal concentration of up to about $\pu{30 m\%{}}$.

If $\ce{H2O2}$ is distilled, the process is performed under reduced pressure with specialized equipment.  A test tube, on the other hand, is not designed for a vacuum distillation; so do not do this.

If the distillation mentioned by you (*which, for safety reasons, you should NOT perform*) aimed to obtain a higher concentrations of $\ce{H2O2}$ as a reagent, consider alternative oxidizers; like the [adduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide_-_urea) of urea and $\ce{H2O2}$; or [oxone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_peroxymonosulfate).  Both solids are powerful oxidizers.

Comment: What if it is only 3% concentrated?